# In App Purchase Legalities Knowledge Share

Tags: react-native, expo, stripe-payments, in-app-purchase

We are planning a monthly membership subscription for our users where accessing this membership gives the user a sub-profile that also gives them extra abilities within the App.

Given this scenario, it would be great to understand if the payment for this membership would need to be handled by Apple/Android pay or can it be handled by an external payment provider (i.e Stripe)

At the moment we have one IAP that gives the user unlimited likes for a week which we implemented using Apple/Android pay as that is a digital product used within the App.

Ideally we’d use stripe because of its extensive API and CRM but I’m all ears and obviously don’t want the headache of our App being removed from the stores for not complying with their payment laws.

Any words of warning/wisdom appreciated!

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Don't take this as a legal advice. My personal opinion is that if the premium content is digital, it still falls under the category of In-App purchase.

There're some documents ([doc1](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay?platform=ios#using-stripe-and-apple-pay-versus-in-app-purchases), [doc2](https://support.stripe.com/questions/apple-pay-or-in-app-purchases-for-mobile-application-payments)) explaining the difference between Apple Pay and In-app purchases. But you should also consider engaging a legal advisor.